# Passing parameters between html pages

Tags: jquery, html, parameters

I am trying to pass parameters between two pages. When the button clicks, it opens page 2 and displaying values in page 1.

In page 1,

```
<li><div id="file1">file1</div><div id="count">1000</div></li>
<li><div id="file2">file2</div><div id="count">2000</div></li>

<a href="page-2.html">Check it out</a>
```

In page 2,

file1 - 1000

file2 - 2000

I want to get the values of files and display them in page 2.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```html
<li><div id="file1">file1</div><div id="count">1000</div></li>
<li><div id="file2">file2</div><div id="count">2000</div></li>

<a href="page-2.html?file1=1000&file2=2000">Check it out</a>
```